# "Right" Answers in the IELTS Reading Section

Tags: semantics, ielts

Friends,

My concerns are about the suggested answers of the Reading section in the *Official IELTS 14 Practice book*. I'm providing the context, question(s) in concern and it's official answer.

1. [image]

the official answer to "What do visitors need to show when parking?" is "permits";
is "*pre-arranged permits*" also ?

2. [image]

the official answer to "Where can the nursery pick-up point be found?" is "Concorde Building";
is "*outside Concorde Building*" also ?

3. [image]

the official answer to "What are Sure Start Maternity Payments?" is "grants";
is "*individual grants*" also ?

I would like to know the logic behind the suggested answers as well as the system evaluators would use to assess alternative answers like I've suggested.

Comment: I would have answered 'outside Concorde Building' too, as the pick-up point obviously isn't _in_ the building. As for the other two, the answers are the nouns, but I have no idea whether the examiners would mark you down for including the adjectives as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a response from an ex-IELTS evaluator online, which was what I was seeking out.

His response was "The answer is yes - all three answers are perfectly fine. The words 'prearranged', 'outside' and 'individual' are not necessary, but they certainly don't make the answers wrong."

[Reference link](https://ielts-simon.com/ielts-help-and-english-pr/2019/08/ielts-reading-problems-with-cambridge-14-answers.html?fbclid=IwAR0AaexLvmJGeVwPZLTjD7IKXQpsu0ZTuRkqms9JmceheUrVq0_eYjwqq38#comments)

Comment: Thank you! The reference link appears not to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, pre-arranged permits is also correct and is in fact more accurate since it does not seem a permit is obtainable by other means according to the passage you supplied.
2. As above but I would state this is more imperative to state as being '*outside Concorde Building*'. In ordinary conversation, we may not know if the building in question has parking within or only without, hence the stronger imperative to be precise.
3. As per the response to question 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you able to vet the response(s) based on your experience as an evaluator or tutor for the IELTS exam? I am looking for a informed validation of sorts.

Comment: I cannot speak to the answers I propose with that authority. All I can tell you is that the answers supplied are not incorrect in ordinary speech.